# SetState outside body reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I try to set state , but I got error "Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."

This is the code import React, { useState } from "react";

```
import AuthService from "../Services/AuthService";

const [Searchfile, setSearchfile] = useState([]);

AuthService.getalldata().then((res) => {
  setSearchfile(res.data);
});

// const Searchfile = [
//   { title: "ayam", singer: "gigi" },
//   { title: "ucuk", singer: "asd" },
// ];

export default Searchfile;
```

Can someone explain to me why that is error and how to fix it ? :D

Comment: The error is clear. You can only use hooks from within the body of a function component. There is no function component in the code provided so you simply cannot use it like this. Are you attempting to create a custom hook? We can't really fix it without knowing what your goal is.

Answer (score 0):

try adding a functional component and paste the code there.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <p> {count}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        click here
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the rules of hooks by attempting to call the useState hook outside of a functional component.  After looking over your code, it seems like you want to create a custom hook of some sort so my suggestion would be todo something like this:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import AuthService from "../Services/AuthService";

const UseSearchFile = () => {
const [Searchfile, setSearchfile] = useState([]);

  AuthService.getalldata().then((res) => {
  setSearchfile(res.data);
});
  
  return {Searchfile}
}

export default UseSearchFile
```

you would then import it where you need it like so:

```
import UseSearchFile from ...correct path
```

and call it like so:

```
const { Searchfile } = UseSearchFile()
```